# What does it mean functions in SML have only one argument?

Tags: sml

So I read that every function in `SML` has one argument and one
result. But I saw examples like:

```
fun foo x y = x + y;
fun goo x y z = 5;
```

Those examples make me think that they get more than one argument.
The signatures:

```
val foo = fn : int -> int -> int
val goo = fn : 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> int
```

The only possible explanation that I can think of, is "syntactic sugar", although I'm not sure. What could be the explanation to this?

Comment: `->` associates to the right. `int -> int -> int` means `int -> (int -> int)` – a function that takes an `int`  and produces an `int -> int` function.

Answer (score 3):

Although your examples seem to take multiple arguments, they actually take one argument at a time.

`foo 1` returns a function that takes `y` as an argument, then when you apply `y`, the function evaluates.

`goo 1` returns a function that takes `y`, which when given returns a function that takes `z`, which when given allows the function to evaluate.

This allows you to easily *partially apply* a function by giving it less arguments than it asks for:

```
val f = foo 1 (* Returns a function *)
val returnVal = f 2 (* Both arguments were given, so the function is fully applied and evaluates *)
```

When combined with functions like `map` or `List.filter`, you can make nice readable code:

```
val keepNegatives = List.filter isNeg

keepNegatives [~1, ~2, 1, ~3]
> [~1, ~2, ~3]
```

Where `isNeg` is a predicate that checks if a number is negative, and `List.filter` is a function that keeps elements from a collection that satisfy the given predicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed some syntactic sugar involved. If I remember correctly,

```
fun foo x y = x + y
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
val rec foo = fn x => (fn y => x + y)
```

So this definition does in fact define a function `foo` that takes a single argument `x` of type `int` and returns a function of type `int -> int`. So the function application `foo 5` returns a function:

```
fn y => 5 + y
```

This returned function can of course also take an argument. This is what looks like a second argument. But notice that this argument is not an argument of `foo` but an argument of the result we get when applying `foo` to its single argument.